# WebMIDI determine music note type by duration?

Tags: web-midi

What is the general direction I should take when it comes to using WebMIDI with a piano connected, to determine the note type(eg quarter note, whole note) of the note played on the piano?

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the time between the note on message and the note off. After have this information, you can compare with your armor scores and bpm. But this is a complicated serie of algorithm for calculate all this dynamic time.
But theorically this is possible if you want information after the note off.